# Using functx:index-of-match-first in XQuery to return a substring of a text node

Tags: xquery, functx

I am trying to write an XQuery which would find all text nodes that contain a given key word in an xml file. The text node is long so I would like to return a substring(of a desired length) of the text starting at the matching key word.

Samplefile.xml

```
<books>
<book>
  <title>linear systems</title>
  <content>vector spaces and linear system analysis </content>
</book>
<book>
  <title>some title</title>
  <content>some content</content>
</book>
</books>
```

samplexquery.xq

```
declare namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com";

for $match_result in /*/book/*[contains(.,'linear')]/text()
  return substring($match_result, functx:index-of-match-first($match_result,'linear'), 50)
```

I expect to get the result [linear systems, linear system analysis]. The title node of first book contains the word 'linear'. Return 50 characters starting from 'linear....'. Similarly for the content node of first book.

I am using XQuery 1.0 and I included the namespace functx as shown in the example at: http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_index-of-match-first.html

But, this is giving me an error: [XPST0017] Unknown function "functx:index-of-match-first(...)".

Thanks,
Sony

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation and solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using XQuery 1.0 and I included
>   the namespace functx as shown in the
>   example at:
>   http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_index-of-match-first.html
>
> But, this is giving me an error:
>   [XPST0017] Unknown function
>   "functx:index-of-match-first(...)".

It is not sufficient to only declare the namespace.

You must also have the code of the function. Only the standard **[XQuery and  XPath functions and operators](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/)** are predefined in the language.

**This corrected code**:

```
declare namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com"; 
declare function functx:index-of-match-first 
  ( $arg as xs:string? ,
    $pattern as xs:string )  as xs:integer? {

  if (matches($arg,$pattern))
  then string-length(tokenize($arg, $pattern)[1]) + 1
  else ()
 } ;

 for $match_result in /*/book/*[contains(.,'linear')]/text()
  return substring($match_result, functx:index-of-match-first($match_result,'linear'), 50)
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (with several non-well-formedness errors corrected):

```
<books>
  <book>
    <title>linear systems</title>
    <content>vector spaces and linear system analysis </content>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title>some title</title>
    <content>some content</content>
  </book>
</books>
```

**produces the expected result**:

```
linear systems linear system analysis
```

**It is a good practice to use the [`import module`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-module-import) directive to import modules from existing libraries of functions**.

Comment: Oh I thought these were pre-defined functions. Looks like they are reusable functions instead. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @sony: It is a good practice to use the `import module` directive to import modules from existing libraries of functions